# pdflatex memoir compiling errors (Undefined control sequence. [\ifmem@noetex])

Tags: pdftex, memoir, texlive, macos

I was trying to change the appearance of my document via memoir package, but have encountered some mistakes when I tried to produce pdf.
The source code for document is pretty simple

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, openany]{memoir}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

But when I run pdflatex, it yields following errors

```
Errors:

/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls:668: Undefined control sequence. [\ifmem@noetex]
/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls:668: Extra \else. [\ifmem@noetex\relax\else]
/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls:670: Extra \fi. [\fi]
/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls:687: Undefined control sequence. [    \openright]
/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls:709: Undefined control sequence. [\if@nyptsizeopt]
/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls:717: Undefined control sequence. [  }]
/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls:717: Undefined control sequence. [  }]
/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls:717: Undefined control sequence. [  }]
/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls:717: Undefined control sequence. [  }]
/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls:717: Class memoir Error: You have used the `*pt' option but [  }]
/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls:722: Extra \else. [\else]
/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls:737: LaTeX Error: File `mem110.clo' not found. [        \input{mem1\@ptsize.clo}]
```

I have tried installing all kinds of extra packages (ended up installing all of them), but no luck yet.
Also, I tried some googling and searching StackExchange, but I don't really know what is the meaning of this mistakes.

Comment: Welcome! First of all ensure you have an up-to-date distribution by running TeX Live Utility.

Comment: The example as posted compiles fine for me with a fully updated TeX system. Maybe your system is not fully up to date. Can you share your complete `.log` file with us (if it is too long to be posted to the question in its entirety upload it to a text sharing website such as https://pastebin.com/ or https://gist.github.com/)?

Comment: @moewe https://pastebin.com/BwFzKuST
I have just updated my distribution, still no luck.

Comment: Also, everything works fine when I compile this document in Texpad, but if I switch to pdflatex (which I am forced to use), this errors show up.

Comment: Your `memoir` is really old `/usr/local/texlive/2019basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls Document Class: memoir 2010/02/20 v1.618033988c` I have `"C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/memoir\memoir.cls" Document Class: memoir 2019/11/21 v3.7j`

Comment: @moewe I tried to run `sudo tlmgr update memoir`, but it says, that there is no updates available

Comment: Do you maybe have several TeX distributions installed and just updated a different installation? Maybe you installed `memoir` manually and not via your TeX distribution. In that case it wouldn't be updated automatically.

Comment: Apparently, reinstalling memoir with not tlmgr, but TeX Live Utility fixed my issue

Comment: Mhh if `tlmgr` does something else than the TeX Live Utility, then that seems to suggest you have two different TeX systems installed and `tlmgr` controls one and TeX Live Utility the other...